# Custom views filter for custom view field

Tags: views, 8

I want to created a custom views field, following [Creating a custom Views field in Drupal 8](https://www.webomelette.com/creating-custom-views-field-drupal-8). This custom field counts and returns the number of referencing entities; if the current view row item is referenced by 10 other entities, the field shows 10.

I want to create a custom exposed filter for this field's output, which is a number between 0 and 100. The filter should allow to show all items that are referenced more than 5 times, for example.

So it would be nice if it is possible to get the int filter options (*Equal to*, *Not equal to*, *Higher than*).

That tutorial also shows a link on creating your own filter; content from this link is used in the duplicate answer that is mentioned. In this custom filter they work with existing fields. Where I want the filter to work with the same calculation (database query) I use in the custom field.

What I got so far is in the .views.inc file.

```php
/* @    -- Total score number/percentage */
$data['tests']['score_percentage'] = array(
  'title' => t('Percentage Filter'),
  'filter' => array(
    'title' => t('Percentage Filter'),
    'help' => t('Provides a custom filter for tests to filter by total score percentage'),
    'id' => 'score_percentage'
  ),
);
```

The *tests* type is a custom entity type I created with the *ECK Entity Types* module.

In the *src/Plugin/views/filter* folder, I have a *ScorePercentage.php* file with the following code.

```php
namespace Drupal\score_percentage\Plugin\views\filter;

use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\DisplayPluginBase;
use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\filter\InOperator;
use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;

/**
 * Filters by given list of node title options.
 *
 * @ingroup views_filter_handlers
 *
 * @ViewsFilter("score_percentage")
 */
class ScorePercentage extends InOperator {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function init(ViewExecutable $view, DisplayPluginBase $display, array &$options = NULL) {
    parent::init($view, $display, $options);
    $this->valueTitle = t('Percentage Filter');
  }

  /**
   * Override the query so that no filtering takes place if the user doesn't
   * select any options.
   */
  public function query() {
    if (!empty($this->value)) {
      parent::query();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Skip validation if no options have been chosen so we can use it as a
   * non-filter.
   */
  public function validate() {
    if (!empty($this->value)) {
      parent::validate();
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone help me creating this exposed filter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a custom views filter handler for a specific field?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/249963/how-to-add-a-custom-views-filter-handler-for-a-specific-field)

Comment: Not a duplicate because they are creating a filter based on a existing field. I would like my filter to be based on a custom views field. The answer in the other thread is based on the article I'm mentioning in my question.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish here. If you want numeric options then make sure the field is an integer?

Comment: I edited my question hopefully it is more clear what I am looking for.

Comment: DId you ever figure this out? I created the filter for the custom views field but there is no table to reference the filtered field to, it throws this error ```SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'node.all_qc_completed' in 'where clause': ... AND (node.all_qc_completed IN (:db_condition_placeholder_2,...```
my definition looks like this ```$data['node']['all_qc_completed'] = array(
    'field' => array(
      'title' => t('Title'),
      'id'    => 'all_qc_completed',
    ),
    'filter' => array(
      'title' => t('Title'),
      'id' => 'yes_no',
    ),
  );

Comment: Have you added the schema file, https://www.webomelette.com/creating-custom-views-filter-drupal-8#comment-1417

Comment: I have used that great webomelette tutorial, however, it is referenced in every post you find in google searches about this topic. Would love to see a different answer, particularly in this context! +1 ^

Comment: I believe if you are using a filter on a pseudo field you will need to include the field key in your `views.inc`: `'field' => 'pseudo_field_id',`. Will go in your `filter` array. And if the field does not exist in the database you need to leave the query empty, or provide a custom query.

Comment: How do you provide a custom query

Comment: Things you might do is leave `public function query()` blank, or do a table join in the query function. But if you leave it as is and the field does not exist in the database you will get a "column not found error". Wish I knew more :)