# How should the view data be defined when adding a custom filter to a field?

Tags: views, 8

[How to add a custom views filter handler for a specific field?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/249963/how-to-add-a-custom-views-filter-handler-for-a-specific-field) answers on how to add a filter to a base field.

I'm looking to add a filter to a non base field. *(The field name is contact).*

Here's what I have so far:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_data_alter().
 */
function custom_contact_views_data_alter(array &$data) {
  $data['node__contact']['active_contact'] = [
    'title' => t('Active contact filter'),
    'filter' => [
      'title' => t('Active contact filter'),
      'help' => 'Filters node on active contact',
      'field' => 'contact_target_id',
      'id' => 'active_contact',
    ],
  ];
}
```

It is added, but it complains about group missing in the Views UI `Error: missing group`

**How should the views data be defined when adding a custom filter to a non-base field?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error `Error: missing group`.

You should be able to fix it by adding the group property, like this:

```
$data['node__contact']['active_contact'] = [
  'title' => t('Active contact filter'),
  'group' => t('Contact'), // Add this line.
  'filter' => [
    // ...
  ],
];
```